# How do I pass a lambda function to regex_replace in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, I am trying to use regex_replace to update some numeric parameters (example is to add 3 all version numbers: "version=3" should become "version=6", "version=2" should become "version=5", ...)

In Python, I can pass a lambda function to re.sub like this:

```
re.sub("version=(\d+)", lambda m: "version=" + str(int(m.group(1))+3), "version=3 blah blah blah whatever version=4")
```

Which gives this as desired:

```
'version=6 blah blah blah whatever version=7'
```

Can't seem to convince Ansible with the right syntax.
I tried this:

```
{{ stringvariable | regex_replace('version=(\\d+)', lambda m: 'version=' + str(int(m.group(1)) + 3) }}
```

Comment: Ansible doesn't permit you to write Python syntax. You can write Jinja syntax, which is Python-like in some ways, but it's **not** Python.

Answer (score 1):

> In Ansible, I am trying to use regex_replace to update some numeric parameters (example is to add 3 all version numbers: "version=3" should become "version=6", "version=2" should become "version=5", ...)

There's nothing magic that needs to take place if you just have **one** string `version=2` and you want to emit `version=5`:

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
      version={{ (stringvar | regex_replace("^version=", "") | int) + 3 }}
  vars:
    stringvar: version=2
```

The tricky bit would be when you have *multiple* of them:

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {% for it in (stringvars | map("regex_replace", "^version=", "") | map("int")) %}
      version={{ it + 3 }}
      {% endfor %}
  vars:
    stringvars:
    - version=2
    - version=5
    - version=7
```